# How to check that a tag contains value or child tag in groovy xmlslurper?

Tags: groovy, xmlslurper

```
def list="<books>
<book>
<title>xx</title>
<year>xxxx</year>
<book>
</books>" (or) 
def list="
<books>
<book> xxxx <book>
</books>";
def books=new XMLSlurper(list);
```

I have requirment like

```
if (books.book has value ) do something 
else if(books.book has tag ) do something
```

Input can be either first or second which differs dynamically. How can I achieve above if condition without any iteration or with single check?.

Comment: A part of your question slipped into the code block. Please fix the formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code :

i hope this code will clarify your requirement.

```
def list1 = "<books><book>xxx</book></books>"

def list2 = "<books><book><new>xxx</new></book></books>"

[list1, list2].each{ text->

def root = new XmlSlurper().parseText(text)


    if (root.book.children().collect{ it.name()})
    {
        println 'book has children : '+ root.book.children().collect{ it.name()}
    }
    else
    {
        println 'book has value :'+root.book
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) .. root.book.children().collect{ it.name()} this is what exactly I am looking for

Comment: @SoundariyaaJakanadhan glad..! enjoy coding..! :)